# Dojo form handling events

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am workin a dojo form and I am trying to improve event handlers

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html

My current application.
http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/254/

```
on(this.resetButton, "click", function(e) {
    return confirm('Press OK to reset widget values');
});
```

how it used to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/252/

with the events inline script on the html template page.

Comment: The `this` will not point to the widget. You need to use `registry.byId("resetButton").on("click", function(e) { ...}`. Also note you need to declare the **id** attribute for the **resetButton** in the button tag.

Comment: I've tried this - but getting an error defining on - http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/260/

Comment: Please delete your answer because it is not an answer it is an update to the question, you can simply update the question.

Comment: I've given you both a tick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is multiple mistake in your code first you are not calling the `on` callback like this

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function (dom,on) {
    on(dom.byId("button"), "click", function (e) {
        console.log("My button was clicked!");
    });
});
```

second you are doing `dom.byId("button")` u have no button with the id button, so you need to specify a specific button ID. like the this:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function (dom,on) {
    on(dom.byId("nextTab"), "click", function (e) {
        console.log("My button was clicked!");
    });
});
```

Check the [jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/264/) .

if you click on the nexttab button it will show the console log message

Comment: but its not working on this form - http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/265/ - for the actual form reset button - it doesn't get invoked
    on(dom.byId("resetButton"), "click", function (e) {
        console.log("reset button was clicked!");
    });

Comment: can you explain to me what do you want ?? do you want to be able to listen to the reset button when it is clicked or you want to use the reset form functionality that is provided by dojo ? and can you please delete your answer, because it is not an answer it is just an update for the question.

Comment: Interesting - so whats the difference between "dojo/ready" and "dojo/domReady!"

Comment: you can have read here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/domReady.html vs http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/ready.html

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it worked for you. and can you please remove your answer because it is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **ready** module to the require function. Then call the entire code with the ready module in a callback.

```
require([
    "dojo/ready", // add the ready module
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/on",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
    "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
    "dijit/form/Select",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (ready, parser, on, registry, ContentPane) {

    // call your the code in the callback.
    ready( function() {

      var progTabCounter = 1;
      makeTab = function () {
         var tc = registry.byId("mainTabContainer");
         var cp = new ContentPane({
             title: 'Programmatically created tab ' + (progTabCounter++),
             closable: true
         });
      cp.domNode.innerHTML = "I was created programmatically!";
      tc.addChild(cp, 0);
     };

    prevTab = function () {
       var tc = registry.byId("mainTabContainer");
       console.log("prev tab", tc);
       var currIndex = tc.getIndexOfChild(tc.selectedChildWidget);
       var tabs = tc.getChildren();
       if (currIndex > 0) {
        tc.selectChild(tabs[currIndex - 1]);
       }

     };

    nextTab = function () {
        var tc = registry.byId("mainTabContainer");
        console.log("next tab", tc);
        var currIndex = tc.getIndexOfChild(tc.selectedChildWidget);
        var tabs = tc.getChildren();
        if (currIndex < tabs.length - 1) {
          tc.selectChild(tabs[currIndex + 1]);
        }
   };


    registry.byId("resetButton").on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("clicked on reset");

        return confirm('Press OK to reset widget values');
    });

    }); // end of ready call

 });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/287/ - latest version - in reference to using ajax calls - how would one go about creating new input fields after listening to say a drop down change - I need to mimic it doing an ajax call, returning input field values and displaying it nicely on the form